# Setting minimum threshold for Watson Tone Analyzer

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson

What file do I change in order to set the minimum threshold for a tone to display in the outputted json for the Watson Tone Analyzer tool? I have read the documentation and cannot find it anywhere.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an explanation of the default responses and the threshold values they recommend:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/tone-analyzer/using-tone.html#using-the-general-purpose-endpoint

And you can change the values in your code. This sample is taken from the Watson Github page:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/food-coach/blob/ca6dc81ebc9a00693816ded348791f9c5ed89dec/addons/tone_detection.js

That's a JavaScript example, but you didn't mention what language you're working with. However, they have similar examples for other languages.